# Galaxy Tab 10.1 automatically select EditText when activity is created

Tags: android, tabs, android-edittext, galaxy

I just had a galaxy tab 10.1, (the last galaxy tab) and it is running Android 3.1.
I installed the app I created and it is containing a lot of EditText to fill. 
The problem is the following :

When an activity is created, if there's EditText on the screen, it automatically open the virtual keyboard to fill the first EditText. Even if I didn't clicked on it. 
Same problem when I scroll a screen : if I scroll, even if I don't click on an EditText, it select one of the screen and open the keyboard automatically.

It's really annoying because it's always doing that.

Did somebody already encountered the same problem ? If so, how to correct it ?

Thank you very much !

Seb

Comment: I have observed this behaviour in Nexus S too. I had a textview fill_parent both height and width. anyway it was ok for me as only textview was available in my view. Hope someone can help you out. may be its happening when u use "Resize" attribute. check it out.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, creating an empty LinearLayout **before** the EditText consumes the focus.

Comment: Does it means that before EACH EditText I'll have to create a Linear Layout ? I'll try but if I knew I would have just bought an old galaxy tab ^^

Comment: Doesn't work even if I put my relativeLayout in a LinearLayout... Doesn't understand what they did with this...